# How to combine 2 fiels with different names but same value in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I set up a ELK environment with 2 different indices(index) streams. both streams have a field with the same value but the filed name is different.
is there a possibility to merge them or something like that so when  i use the Kibana filter it shows me the value from both filed.

so i can set up visualizations, but when i filter on stream 1, the visualization of stream 2 is empty.

i also tried to name the indedx the same, but did not help.

Example:
index1 fieldname information.ID = 123
index2 fieldname ID = 123

i want to use the filter on both streams

Comment: What kind of visualization are you trying to do? Can you show a screen of how it currently looks for you? Is it possible to modify the index structures so that the fields match? How are you loading your data into Kibana?

Comment: I don't think you can, when you filter on a dashboard this filter is applied to all the visualizations on that dashboard, if you have two index and one of them does not have the field you are filtering, the visualizations for that index won't show any data. You will need to change the name of the field or create a new one with the same value and same name of the field from the first index.

Comment: i use this instruction: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/visualizing-amazon-guardduty-findings/ and added a second stream wich will import a csv via logstash to kibana. this csv hat the columns "Plugin ID" "Risk" "Host" "Name" "Synopsis" "Description" "Solution"
GuardDuty delivers the ec2 instance over the field: detail.resource.instanceDetails.instanceId  
the CSV over "Host" so now i want to add the findings from the CSV to the dashboard that i have additional informations about my instances from the csv

Comment: I have some troubles understanding your comment, but It seems the easier solution would be to modify the Logstash that loads the CSV into Kibana so that the structure matches the original one. You can use something like [the Mutate filter and add_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias which contains both indexes. Write a query against the alias using script fields.
In script fields you can define the new field and its source logic from underlying documents.

```
 "script_fields": {
    "my_script_field": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "doc['some_field'].value + doc['another_field'].value" 
      }
```

In this way the resultset will have single field “my_script_field”